# Young Adult Novel About Apprentice Healer

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, medieval, medicine

I read a book in high school about a healer apprentice who falls in love with a woman during a plague. He catches it due to his profession and cannot give her and their child a kiss goodbye before he leaves to die. That was towards the end of the book, I cannot remember anything else except the intro where he is assisting his teacher perform surgery (he ties the patient's veins closed, etc.).
I remember it has a purple/blue cover and there is a picture of a blonde man in a cloak either with his hand outstretched or holding tools. I read it between 2005-2006 but it could have been printed earlier. It's been driving me crazy not being able to find it with a general search.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE!  Was there a science fiction or fantasy element to the story?